# KeyPressed()/KeyReleased() Fires Repeatedly when key held down [WINDOWS]

Tags: java, keylistener

Before you mark this as a repeat question, I must clarify; the other people that have had this problem had Linux based systems; I am using Windows.

I have this in my Input method, designed to get the input from the user, and add the key codes to an array list.  The problem is, when I am holding the key down, keyPressed() and keyReleased() just gets fired repeatedly, instead of keyPressed() firing once, and keyReleased() firing once the key is actually released.  Is there any way to make this happen, or some sort of work around?

What I'm using:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Fired Press");
    if (!keysPressed.contains(e.getKeyCode()))
        keysPressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Fired Release");
    keysReleased.add(e.getKeyCode());
    for (int i = 0; i < keysPressed.size(); i++)
        if (keysReleased.contains(keysPressed.get(i)))
            keysPressed.remove(i);
}
```

It should be stated that every tick, the keysReleased ArrayList is cleared of all data.

Thanks

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: Added my code.  Just add it to a KeyListener (along with the ArrayLists) and it should work fine.